# How to delete specific characters in a text file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have the following lines in a text file:

```
1 Q0 /home/nikol123/Downloads/Ergasia_1/Ergasia_1/metadata/13/120411.xml 1 
1 Q0 /home/nikol123/Downloads/Ergasia_1/Ergasia_1/metadata/11/105016.xml 2 
1 Q0 /home/nikol123/Downloads/Ergasia_1/Ergasia_1/metadata/15/149972.xml 3 
1 Q0 /home/nikol123/Downloads/Ergasia_1/Ergasia_1/metadata/12/110688.xml 4
```

and I want to keep only these data:

```
1 Q0 120411 1 
1 Q0 105016 2 
1 Q0 149972 3 
1 Q0 110688 4
```

namely to keep from each line from the path `/home/nikol123/Downloads/Ergasia_1/Ergasia_1/metadata/13/120411.xml` for example only the number `120411` and so on...

Answer (score 2):

Try `awk` with `/`, `.`, and  (space) as a field separators:

```
awk -F'[/. ]' '{print $1 " " $2 " " $11 " " $13}' file
```

Output:

```
1 Q0 120411 1
1 Q0 105016 2
1 Q0 149972 3
1 Q0 110688 4
```

Comment: Great!That works!

Answer (score 1):

Try sed:

```
sed 's/\(1 Q0\).*\/\(.*\)\.xml\( .*\)/\1 \2\3/' file
```

OR

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\/home.*\/\(.*\)\.xml\( .*\)/\1\2\3/' file
```

Output:

```
1 Q0 120411 1 
1 Q0 105016 2 
1 Q0 149972 3 
1 Q0 110688 4
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution with `sed` (OSX & BSD):

```
sed -E 's!([0-9]*) (Q0) [a-zA-Z0-9_/]*/([0-9]*).xml ([0-9])!\1 \2 \3 \4!g' file.txt
```

After if you need different pattern (like Q0 is not a constant...) you have to adapt it.